# How to fix 'No componentRef found in DetachedRouteHandle'

Tags: angular, nativescript, modalviewcontroller, router-outlet, angular-nativescript

I am trying to show a modal from a component that sits in a different module than the one where the modal sits. The modal is a navigation modal, so I first load the `RootModalComponent` that has a router `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>` and `onInit` I redirect to the first modal. All this first part works well, but when I close the first modal, I get this error:

```
CONSOLE ERROR [native code]: ERROR Error: No componentRef found in DetachedRouteHandle

CONSOLE ERROR [native code]: ERROR CONTEXT {
"view": {
"def": {
...
"name": "page-router-outlet",
"attrs": [],
"template": null,
"componentProvider": null,
"componentView": null,
"componentRendererType": null,
"publicP
```

This error is triggered when I call the method below from the `FirstModalComponent`:

```
onClose(): void {
    this.modalParams.closeCallback();
}
```

The weirdest thing is that when I close the modal from the `SecondModalComponent`, everything is fine!

I Followed the `Nativescript` doc: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/modal-view-ng to implement navigation with modal views, except that my router config is quite different and the `RootModalComponent` is not being called by a component from the same `module`.

**markers-routing.Module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'first-modal', component: FirstModalComponent },
    { path: 'second-modal', component: SecondModalComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class MarkersModalRoutingModule {}
```

**markers.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        FirstModalComponent,
        SecondModalComponent,
        RootModalComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        MarkersModalRoutingModule
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    entryComponents: [
        RootModalComponent
    ]
})
export class MarkersModalModule { }
```

**root-modal.component.ts**

```
export class RootModalComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private router: RouterExtensions,
        private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.navigate(['first-modal'], { relativeTo: this.activeRoute });
    }

}
```

**root-modal.component.html**

```
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

Does someone know a workaround?

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here you can find a playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=vyv4kI&v=9

Comment: @Manoj I now have another error in the playground which I can't fix either, it says `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FirstModalComponent -> ModalDialogParams]`! I don't have this error in my project...

Comment: I didn't find time to fix the Playground but to fix that issue, you must include `ModalDialogService` in `providers`. Besides having a quick look at your code, I don't think your modal dialogs can be lazily loaded. It has to be part of your home module or app module.

Comment: @Manoj adding the `ModalDialogService` in `providers` did not work as you can see on this playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=vyv4kI&v=11 ! Additionally, when I put all components inside the AppModule, the same error is triggered... `No componentRef found in DetachedRouteHandle`

Answer (score 2):

Currently, we need a workaround to make it work because there is a bug in the `nativescript angular` framework (see [issue 1774](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1774)).

Basically, the workaround consists in naming the `page-router-outlet` inside the `root-modal.component.html` (in the example below I named it `sharedModal`). You then use this name to navigate to the other modals.

For example:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { sharedModal: ["first-modal"] } }], { relativeTo: this.activeRoute });
```

Find here a fully developed `nativescript playground` sample: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=TkK7sQ&v=5

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should include `ModalDialogService` in `providers`. Also I don't think you could load modal dialog routes lazily, it should be part of your current module (in your case `HomeModule`). You don't have to import `HomeModule` in app module as it's being loaded lazily from app routing.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=vyv4kI&v=12)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still get the `ModalDialogService` error and concerning the modals, I added all components to the `HomeModule` and I still get the same error `No componentRef found in DetachedRouteHandle`... this is really weird

Comment: Which device you are testing it with? It works perfectly fine on my end, please make sure the Playground version is correct one (v12).

Comment: Sorry... apparently I was not using the proper version, my bad. Could be that the version on my preview app was stuck on an older version, it works well now. Unfortunatley I can't recreate the bug I have... thanks for your help touhg

Comment: Did you already get an error like this `No component factory found for RootModalComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?` while the component is still inside the entryComponents of the `HomeModule`?

Comment: Would it be possible that all of this is caused because I am achieving all of this inside a tab component?

Comment: I didn't get any error, the version I have shared works for me, I was able to navigate within modal pages. Using them inside Tab has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I created a new Playground where I added a tab navigation, now there is an error with the url segment that is not recognized: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=NRmf4z and the error is `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'first-modal'`... any idea?

Comment: In youe sample RootModalComponent is missing

Comment: @Narendra Sorry I added the wrong playground, this is the one: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=VdmiR9&v=8